# Is null a primitive type or object or bug in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, null

I have been looking for the answer and gone through articles where some says its bug in javascript and consoling it in browser gives object.If so then why (null === null) is true.can anyone give clear explanation regarding this?

Comment: What exactly do you think is a "bug"?

Comment: The answer is confusingly both yes and no. `typeof null` producing `object` was a mistake at the very start. However, since then it has been codified in the spec, so it's not behaviour as expected. That has no bearing on `null === null`, however - the two values are the same - it's the same missing value both times. If the spec said they shouldn't be equal *then* the equality holding up would be a problem. As it stands, the specs say the opposite. The only value not equal to itself is `NaN` and that's not a mistake, either. Just initially confusing.

Comment: `null` is unequivocably a primitive value: https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-null-type . `typeof` is just a strange operator.